# Join two strings and get rid of list regex

Tags: python, string, pandas, join

I have a dataframe containing 2 parts of string in column B, extracted with regex from column A:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.findall(r'([S][\d]|[V][\d]{3})')

                       A                                     B
1   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N002_V087_1785984_12593       ['S1', 'V087']
2   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N003_V023_5896589_15105       ['S1', 'V023']
3   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N004_V155_2541236_11033       ['S1', 'V155']
```

I would like to get rid of lists in column B and join two strings within with `'_'`

Result would look like this:

```
                       A                            B
1   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N002_V087_1785984_12593   S1_V087
2   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N003_V023_5896589_15105   S1_V023
3   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N004_V155_2541236_11033   S1_V155
```

Another thing i want to extract with regex from column A is this part of string looking like this:

```
I have no idea how the regex would look!

                A                                      C
1   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N002_V087_1785984_12593   S1_1785984
2   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N003_V023_5896589_15105   S1_5896589
3   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N004_V155_2541236_11033   S1_2541236
```

Sorry for the double question, i would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one you just have to apply '_'.join in B:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply('_'.join)
```

Second, you don't need regex, just split by '_' and get the values you need and then join again:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join([x.split('_')[4], x.split('_')[-2]]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use: `str.join("_")`

**Ex:**

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.join("_") 
print(df['B'])
```

**Output:**

```
0    S1_V087
1    S1_V023
2    S1_V155
Name: B, dtype: object
```

**[MoreInfo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html)**

---

To extract content using regex

```
df['C'] = "S1_" + df['A'].str.extract("(\d+)_\d+$")  
print(df['C'])
```

**Output:**

```
0    S1_1785984
1    S1_5896589
2    S1_2541236
Name: C, dtype: object
```